# Pick a tab from URL in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make this script pick an active tab based on what the url has at the end.

Example: http://example.com?tab=3

Then GET the tab value and make the script show that tab as active. I can't get it to work. Any help would be great.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the real attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the real attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#tab1">Current Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Add New Event</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">Upcoming Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab4">Past Events</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">

<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
<h2>Current Events for $today</h2>

</div> 

<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
<h2>Add New Event</h2>

</div> 

<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
<h2>Upcoming Events</h2>

</div> 

<div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
<h2>Past Events</h2>

</div> 

</div> 
</div>
```

Of course there is some CSS and other stuff so please don't point that out lol. I am just trying to get the java script to take the $tab=_$GET['tab']; and make that tab visible.

So really all I need is a rewrite of the JavaScript to make it work.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. I fixed it for you, but please note that these are very different technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use `hashtags` for js version, or pass `$_GET['tab']` into js script with PHP.
In such cases people usualy using `hashtags`.

In first case, you have to use `hashtags` and make your url look like this : http://example.com/#tab1 and add in your js accepting of these `hashtag`:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

In second case, you should use PHP to pass tab value into JS, and your js code would look like this:

```
var currentTab = <?=$_GET['tab']?>;
```

Comment: So I got it working with the window.location.hash;, but it still will not highlight the tab that i send it to. I have tried everything I can think of in that script to make it turn the active tab white when I send to it via link. They turn white when I click on them but not using the link. Any ideas?

Comment: Make them active with your JS